# Google colab not showing output

Tags: python, performance, google-chrome, output, google-colaboratory

Python code not running in google colab, means simple hello world b print nh ho raha, just write print("hello world") cell execution ho jati ✓ a jata side pr but output show nh rahi, means likha huwa hello worla as output show nh ho raha, isi tarha baqi functions b execution ho jati ✓ tic b ho jata but output show nh ho rahi, kindly give solution,

Trying to output in colab as print hello world as output but none showing anything